# How to enable C++17 on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, c++17, darwin

I am able to update gcc on Linux to get `-std=c++17`, but cannot do the same on Mac.
Is there a version of Clang I can update to or some other alternative to get C++ 17 on my Mac?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can also have gcc on Mac.

Answer (score 28):

On my 10.11 El Capitan, Xcode 7.3.1, clang has been updated to:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
```

which is almost equivalent to llvm version 3.8. `clang++` hasn't `-std=c++17` option, but `-std=c++1z`, working well at present, though only supporting some features of C++1z.

For gcc, you can install a very new one by:

```
brew install gcc --HEAD
```

which will install gcc-6.1 now, (2016.8). This gcc has limited support for C++17 and can be enabled by `-std=c++17`.

---

some update:

The corresponding llvm version of Apple's clang is not clear recently, should be 3.9+ or 4+. Check [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions) for more information.

`brew install gcc --HEAD` should always work for mac/homebrew, and give you the cutting edge gnu gcc with many experimental features. On the other hand, normal `brew install gcc` should install a gcc supporting most c++17 features now.

For the language standard argument, try `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++1z` for different compilers, one of them should work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and worked. had to make CXX=g++- instead of g++ on the Darwin build.

Answer (score 9):

Apple's Clang already supports up to the latest C++ version but is defaulted to older ones.

All you have to do is add `--std=c++17` after `g++` while execution,  execute your code with `g++ --std=c++17 <filename>.cpp`

If you're using code runner for execution, follow:

1. `Code>Preferences>Settings` in search bar at top of settings type `code-runner.executormap`,
   [image]
2. Select `Edit in settings.json`, A Json file file open
   [image]
3. from this`settings.json` file change the line with key `cpp` `line:8` in following example
   `"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ --std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",`

4. Restart VSCode

Answer (score 6):

The v17 standard is now offered by default with [Xcode 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes), offering both standard, and variant flavors.

**Via Build Settings:**

> *CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD* : C++17/GNU++17

**CLI:**

> `-std=c++17`  *[partial support](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17)*
> `-std=gnu++17`

Comment: Note that (IIUC) C++17 features are still [partially supported](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html).

Comment: Thanks @FranklinYu! I updated the post to point out partial support for the Clang implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can install gcc from sources (it's not complex at all) if there are some complications with the repositories.

Installation process for [mac os X](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/05/10/compiling-gcc-6-mac-os-x/), and here it is for [linux](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gcc.html).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first install a compiler that supports the C++17 standard.  I can only recommend installing gcc, clang, and Apple's LLVM:

- gcc 9 or 10
- clang 9 or 10
- XCode LLVM 9.3 or later

Others such as, PGI, Intel Compiler, etc. might work, but I have no experience with those.

gcc and clang can be installed using homebrew

gcc:

```
brew install gcc
```

clang

```
brew install llvm
```

You can get XCode through the App Store.

---

On a Mac, the C++17 Parallel STL requires Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB).

The easiest way to install tbb is through homebrew:

```
brew install tbb
```

When compiling from the command line using gcc or clang don't forget to include the flag:
-std=c++17

Answer (score -6):

Maybe you should install xcode command tool using:

```sh
xcode-select --install
```