# C++ Build Failed on Xcode OSX with multiple errors File IO ... is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, file-io

I am getting the following error whenever I try to build my code on Xcode on my Mac.

My current system:
macOS: version 10.15.1 (19B88)
Xcode: Version 11.2.1 (11B500)

**my error:**

> 'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
>   'current_path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
>   'operator/' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
>   'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
>   'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "being exectued from:" << endl;
    cout << argv[0] << endl;

    std::__fs::filesystem::path cwd = std::__fs::filesystem::current_path() / "filename.txt"; // C++17
    cout << "but the input.txt and output.txt files should be be in the following directory:" << endl;
    cout << cwd.string() << endl << endl;
```

After running `g++` on terminal I get

> clang: error: no input files

And after running `g++ --version` I get

> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images.  Not everyone can see pictures.

Comment: okay changing rn

Comment: What version of macOS do you have?

Comment: Version of XCode?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I'm still on Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: @LarryB Version 11.2 (11B52)

Comment: There error says that you need 10.15.  You'll need to upgrade.

Comment: Good Lord. I need to update an entire system to just run a code.

Comment: `filesystem` depends on OS support.  You need an OS that supports it in order to use it.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I updated my macOS and xcode to the latest and I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: why are you doing `std::__fs::filesystem` instead of `std::filesystem`?

Comment: Your project _must_ use the 10.15 SDK; change it in your project settings. This has nothing to do with what version of the OS _you_ are running; it is about what you are targeting.

Comment: So basically I needed to use the 10.15 SDK regardless of what version my OS was ruuning. Thank you so much @BradAllred for taking time to helping this poos soul out. Everything is working perfectly fine now. Thank you again man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SDK 10.15, Xcode 11 and and enabling C++17 compiler solved this issue.

To enable C++17, followi this link: [Enable C++17 on Xcode, macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091173/how-to-enable-c17-on-mac)

On your Xcode, from General setting, select **10.15** SDK as **Deployment Target** and you are good to go for .

Comment: Nice, but it's dirty marketing tricks from Apple. It's C++17 standard and nothing prevented to distribute proper c++ libs with Xcode no matter what host OS version used. Also CLang can be used not only from Xcode... what about CMake/Make? - nothing...

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
CONFIG += c++17
```

and

```
macx: {
    QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.15
}
```

to your .pro file.
That should set `-std=gnu++1z -mmacosx-version-min=10.15` flags to compiler.
Also I used Apple Clang compiler both for C++ and C (may be set in *Preferences -> Kits*). Not sure if it is critical, but GCC did not work definitely.