# Unable to use to_chars with clang++ on MacOs

Tags: c++, macos, stl, clang++

I've tried to use `g++` and `clang++`, I've tried various c++ versions with the -std flag. I have tried reading the `charconv` file to see what the issue may be.

I could use some help, I'm really unsure of how to move forward.

I have MacOS 13.3 and clang version `Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.28.1.1)`

edit:

Minimal Code:

```
#include <charconv>
using namespace std;

char buf[30] = {0};

int main()
{
  const auto to_result = to_chars(buf, buf+30, 32.3, chars_format::scientific, 5);
  return 1;
}
```

Minimal build:

```
> clang++ test.cpp -std=c++17
test.cpp:7:26: error: 'to_chars' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 13.3
  const auto to_result = to_chars(buf, buf+30, 32.3, chars_format::scientific, 5);
                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/charconv:815:17: note: 'to_chars' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
to_chars_result to_chars(char* __first, char* __last, double __value, chars_format __fmt, int __precision);
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Which version of macOS do you have?

Comment: please put the key code here. we just need a MINIMAL example that demonstrates the behavior. not your whole program.

Comment: what version of clang / g++ are you using?

Comment: @UpAndAdam I provided the details in the post as an edit

Comment: @Jarod42 I have 13.3

Comment: @UpAndAdam edited to init buf. Not sure how that was undefined though.. the buffer would have been allocated on the stack, no? I realize the values in it would be undefined, but the address should be valid. Am I missing something?

Comment: The error message suggests you are NOT on 13.3.   what version of xcode is installed? i take it you didnt install clang yourself?

Comment: sorry you are right undefined value. not UB

Comment: I'm on Xcode version 14.1

Comment: ```
> sw_vers
ProductName:            macOS
ProductVersion:         13.3
```

Comment: Is adding flag `-mmacosx-version-min=13.3` help?

Comment: Related to [c-build-failed-on-xcode-osx-with-multiple-errors-file-io-is-unavailable-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943032/c-build-failed-on-xcode-osx-with-multiple-errors-file-io-is-unavailable-i) (issue with other version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jarod42 - the answer was adding `-mmacosx-version-min=13.3`