# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:61: Your compiler does not fully support the C++17 standard and libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to install a library from https://github.com/Koihik/LuaFormatter, and I got an error when I am using `cmake .`

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- IPO / LTO enabled
-- Looking for C++ include filesystem
-- Looking for C++ include filesystem - not found
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:30 (message):
  filesystem not found, use experimental/filesystem as fallback.  It's
  recommended to use a stable C++17 compliant compiler/libstdc++.
```

I am not a C++ developer and I am not sure what is the next step I need to take. I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091173/how-to-enable-c17-on-mac), it seems like I need to have **gcc 9 or 10**, **clang 9 or 10** and **XCode LLVM 9.3 or later**. I have installed all packages, but it is still not working. These are my version check:

```
❯ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Is gcc the problem here? It is `Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`

```
❯ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
❯ xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2354.
```

**Update**

Following this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler/99157#99157), I have made an alias in `.zshrc`, but still I can't build correctly:

```
alias gcc='gcc-10'
alias cc='gcc-10'
alias g++='g++-10'
alias c++='c++-10'
```

**Update 2**

This is the error I am getting when I `cmake .`

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8010.dir/fs.cpp.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_a8010/fast] Error 2


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:61 (message):
  Your compiler does not fully support the C++17 standard and libraries
```

Comment: What error have you got? I see only the warning.

Comment: Updated with the error I am getting. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: This is not the error. This is the logged result of the internal test, that is performed by cmake. I still doubt you got errors.

Comment: Um these are all the logs I got. How can I inspect that error?